# Angular route wildcard possible/workaround?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wildcard, routes

I made a isActive function to set the active class on a menu element.

The function is as follow:

```
   $scope.isActive = function (path) {
        if (path == $location.path()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my HTML is just use:

```
   <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/page')}">
   <a href="page">Page</a></li>
```

But this HTML is only defined once in my template. So it would be really great to use:

```
   isActive('/page*')
```

So that everything beyond the '/page' URL will get the active state.

Does anyone knows a workaround, because I haven't found it yet on the forums and the angular documention, so I guess this isn't there yet..

Comment: Why don't you use ngRouter for that? I would strongly suggest ui-router : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: I got it working atm. But thanks, I will have a look at it today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this ?

```
$scope.isActive = function (path) 
{

    var strRegExPattern = '\\b'+path+'\\b'; 

    if( document.location.pathname.match(new RegExp(strRegExPattern,'g')) )
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know if you can substitute

```
document.location.pathname.match(... // VANILLA JS
```

with

```
$location.path().match(... // NG JS
```

...give it a try.

Comment: It worked man. Thanks alot! I'm sure people will like this solution!
Hope that angular will add it to the core tho. Convenient functionality..